# Create Short code dynamically

Tags: plugins, shortcode, gallery

I want to generate short code for my gallery dynamically. For a single gallery, it is easy to create a short code for my gallery using

```
add_shortcode( 'image-gallery', 'gallery' )
```

Now my question is how can i create multiple short code for multiple gallery? Like for gallery 1 short code will be image-gallery-1, for 2 code will be image-gallery-2. I've tried this way

```
$all_gallery = $wpdb->prefix . 'gallery';
$all=$wpdb->get_results("select * from $all_gallery");
if(count($all)>0){
   foreach ($all as $a){
      add_shortcode( 'image-gallery-'.$a->id, 'gallery' );
   }
}
```

Its working nicely but when i deactivate the plugin and  then activate the plugin again, a fatal error occurred and plugin is unable to activate.

Comment: Where is this code? Please include the context.

Answer (score 1):

*I cannot comment, I would if I could, but I can't, please don't down-vote*

Could you not just use 1 shortcode with a parameter, e.g. instead of create one for each gallery `image-gallery-1`,`image-gallery-2` etc, you could just use the ID as a parameter: `image-gallery 1`, `image-gallery 2` ...

Then in your handling function you can simply test the parameter to see which gallery it is, I think this method is also slightly better for performance too as you don't need to call `add_shortcode` as many times, and all you are doing is removing one hyphen :)